# Get next-older tag for a given commit?

Tags: python-3.x, gitpython

I'm trying to figure out the next-older tag for a given commit. I currently have the following function:

```
def next_older_tag(commit):
    repo = commit.repo
    for tag in repo.tags:
        if tag.commit.committed_datetime >= commit.committed_datetime:
            continue
        return tag
```

After consulting the docs, I could not find a better way to go about this - am I right about this? It works, but it feels like there should be a better way to do this.